# Write a line with for-loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, variables

I want to define the variable `xx` exactly like this:

```
xx = ('xx_1','xx_2','xx_3','xx_4','xx_5')
```

with python using a `for` loop. Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Unfortunately, this is not a code-writing or tutorial site, and we ask that questions include a [mcve] including _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research, and what went wrong with your attempt(s)

Answer (score 1):

`xx = tuple('xx_' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6))`

The documentation that you were looking for is here:
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/

Answer (score 0):

*As a joke,*

```
xx = tuple()
for x in ('xx_1', 'xx_2', 'xx_3', 'xx_4', 'xx_5'):
    xx += (x, )
```

@Mark's answer is what you are looking for. Next time please post your attempt so we can help, instead of just writing a solution for you.